# Is possible deploy applications developed with GWT 2.x on Jboss 4?

Tags: gwt, servlets, jboss

I want to know if is possible deploy GWT 2.x applications on server with support for the servlet spec 2.4 like JBoss 4.

I have reviewed the official documentation but apparently there is no dependences. So my questions are:

1. Is possible?
2. Is needed workarounds?
3. Any has some previous experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes It is possible. You can deploy GWT applicaions to any external web server like Tomcat, Jboss etc. Your question is bit wide in context. So, better look at some tutorials.

This [tutorial](http://techforb.blogspot.in/2007/09/gwt-with-extenal-application-server.html) will help you more. I have not gone into details of this but seems good.